# How to get the frequency of items in the specific columns of a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `mydf`. I want to get the count for each item in combination column to get the result as shown below.

```
   mydf <-structure(c("AMLM12001KP", "AMLM120XP", "AMLM12001KP", "1231401", 
            "1231401", "1231401", "ANKRD30BL*", "WDR70*NXPH1", "WDR70*NXPH1", 
            "FGGY*", "LIN28A*DFNB59", "AK2*"), .Dim = c(6L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
                NULL, c("customer_sample_id", "combination")))
```

result

```
combination      frequency    customer_sample_id
ANKRD30BL*       1 sample     AMLM12001KP 
WDR70*NXPH1      2 sample     AMLM120XP, AMLM12001KP
FGGY*            1 sample     1231401
LIN28A*DFNB59    1 sample     1231401
AK2*             1 sample     1231401
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With base R:

```
aggregate(customer_sample_id ~ combination, data = mydf,
          FUN = function(x) c(length(x), paste(x, collapse = ",")))
```

or with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
library(data.table)
mydt <- as.data.table(mydf)
mydt[, .(freq = .N, customer_sample_id = paste(customer_sample_id, collapse = ",")), by = combination]
```

or with [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr):

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(mydf) %>% 
  group_by(combination) %>% 
  summarise(freq = n(), customer_sample_id = paste(customer_sample_id, collapse = ","))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciated